# Granting sudo access for specific command and any flags set (RedHat)

Tags: linux, redhat, sudo

How can you grant sudo access for a specific command with flags.

Ex. I requested sudo access for this command below:

```
sudo /usr/bin/su - wassa /usr/was7/profiles/dmgr/bin/wsadmin.sh
```

I can run the above command but cannot run any of the below commands (it will prompt for password then say I do not have the required access):

```
sudo /usr/bin/su - wassa /usr/was7/profiles/dmgr/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -c "AdminApplication.stopApplicationOnCluster('app', '$APP_CLUSTER')"
sudo /usr/bin/su - wassa /usr/was7/profiles/dmgr/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -c "AdminApplication.stopApplicationOnCluster('app', '$APP_CLUSTER')"
```

I know I could easily request each command separately (which I may have to anyway because of the companies policy), but I want to avoid it in case I need to make any script changes, I won't want to have to submit another ticket and wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` allows shell-style **wildcards** (aka meta or glob characters) to be used in host names, path names and **command line arguments** in the [`sudoers`](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html#x57696c646361726473) file.

`*` Matches any set of zero or more characters.

`?`
Matches any single character.

`[...]`
Matches any character in the specified range.

`[!...]`
Matches any character not in the specified range.

`\x`
For any character ‘x’, evaluates to ‘x’. This is used to escape special characters such as: `‘*’, ‘?’, ‘[’, and ‘]’`.

So you could define something along the lines of this to allow both the command with or without arguments:

```
leeman24 ALL=(wassa) /usr/was7/profiles/dmgr/bin/wsadmin.sh, /usr/was7/profiles/dmgr/bin/wsadmin.sh -*
```